# Rust sqlx: there is no query finalizers

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-sqlx

The issue is when I type code like this.

```rust
let data = sqlx::query("SELECT id, name FROM test")
        .fetch_all(&pool)
        .await;
```

I get an `` no method named `fetch_all` found for struct `sqlx_core::query::Query<'_, _>` in the current scope `` error. Following official [getting started readme](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx#usage).
This is also applicable to the `query_as` method. I suspect that for some reason the compiler doesn't "see" `sqlx::Query` trait methods, but I don't know how to bring them in scope.

Although when I use macro `sqlx::query!`, `.fetch_all` does exist.

Also, there is an inconvenience that `rust-analyzer` LSP tells me that the type of the `data` variable is `std::result::Result<[type error], [type error]>`, which removes any possibility of using autocompletion and type checking, other than running (notoriously slow) rust compiler.

*P.S. I use PostgreSQL as a database solution, if that may help.*

*P.S.S. env variable DATABASE_URL is set at the compile-time and is correct, so macros do all of the compile-time validation stuff.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsing docs.rs a bit, I found that type `sqlx::Query` does not even have finalizers other than `fetch`. As for `sqlx::query_as`, the trait I was looking for was called `PgQueryAs`, which actually contains `fetch_all`, `fetch_optional`, `fetch_one`, etc. And adding `use sqlx::postgress::PgQueryAs` fixed the problem for me.

Despite that, I still don't know a solution for evaluating macros to get decent types in my IDE.